# Why is my .NET 2.0 ActiveX Control reporting its version as 0.0.0.1 in IE's Manage Add-ons?

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, activex

From the Details section of the property tab of my control's dll:

> File version 9.0.1.38589
>   Product version 9.0.1.38589

`[assembly: AssemblyVersion("9.0.1.38589")]`Shows up in reflector.

However, for some reason Manage Add-ons is reporting the control as version 0.0.0.1.

I've been unable to find any information on how this number is determined.

Comment: Have you set any AssemblyVersionAttribute and related attributes?

Comment: Yes. Both AssemblyVersionAttribute and AssemblyFileVersionAttribute are being set.  The result is that those versions are showing up in the details tab of the file properties.

Comment: Hmm, [AssemblyVersion] does *not* normally show up in the shell property sheet.  Are you doing something with the unmanaged version resource?

Comment: Added another note on AssemblyVersion as gotten from reflector.  It might be possible that obfuscation is somehow mangling unmanaged resources.  How would I inspect the unmanaged version resource?